# Is $f(z) = \frac{Re(z)}{1+|z|}$ continuous at $z=0$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Is $f(z) = \frac{Re(z)}{1+|z|}$ continuous at $z=0$?

Suppose that $z = x+yi$, then:

$$f(z) = \frac{x}{1+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

I'd say that if we take this limit along $y=0$ we'd have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{1+|x|} = 0$$

and along $x=0$ we'd have the limit being $0$, so for now it seems that this function could be continuous at $z=0$.

Now take $y=x$, then:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{2x^2}} = 0$$

too. Again, no problems.

Maybe it indeed is continuous at $z=0$? How could I prove that?

Comment: Try polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is indeed $0$, since both $\textrm{Re}(z)$ and $1 + \vert z \vert$ are continuous and $1 + \vert z \vert$ is never $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a standard $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ proof.

Let $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{2}$. If $|z| < \delta < 2\varepsilon < 1$, then

$$|f(z)| = \left|\frac{\Re(z)}{1+|z|}\right| \le \frac{|z|}{1+|z|} < \delta/2 < \varepsilon.$$

Therefore, $f$ is continuous at the origin.